# Create a new Controller manually and face with "View not Found" error in Yii

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I use basic template of yii, i create a new controller manually in `Controllers` Folder and name it `CountryController.php` and put bellow codes in it.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

But when i type `http://localhost/sites/basic/web/index.php?r=country%2Findex` in browser i get following Exception:

> View not Found yii\base\ViewNotFoundException

[This is image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDYcM.jpg)

On the other side when i type `http://localhost/sites/basic/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex`in the browser it renders index view correctly.

**Why this happen? can i create a Controller manually? How?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not saying it can't find the page, just that it can't find the view file. Along with your controller, you should also have created a view file `app\views\country\index.php` This is the file you are referring to when you call `$this->render('index').

Comment: thanks. The problem was i refer to index view in site folder